# Denoise Autoencoder test set got same results with different input

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning, autoencoder

I built a denoise autoencoder from example : https://github.com/aymericdamien/TensorFlow-Examples/blob/master/examples/3_NeuralNetworks/autoencoder.py
I worked well with this example

I changed nothing but the input data to audio data from a WAV song.
The input data is coverted to e.g. float32(batch_size, n_input), range (0,1).
The input data is generated from origin with salt and pepper noise (that is: some potion of data are set to 0, some potion are set to 1; in my test, 20% are changed)

Then I use it for training, however, after lots of tests, I noticed that: for different test set data, the trained model get almost the same result for each sequence. While I also used np.random sequence to test, the result is different from test set result.

Do anyone has ideas what's possible wrong with it? Thanks

Comment: Could you clarify what you mean by: _for different test set data, the trained model get almost the same result for each sequence_ ?

Comment: @Cedias for exampe, two test data (not real, just for explain) [0.1,0.2,0.3,0.4];[0.4,0.4,0.4,0.4] got same result such as [0,1,0,1]. I'm wondering whether it's because overfit or the feature of training data is too bad that it cannot genrate a proper result